# JS newbie: Why is this function inside a for loop called only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I'm learning JS and using chrome dev tools console to run the code. Why does the following code only makes one call to `randomNumbe()` if it is inside a for loop?

```
function randomNumber(){
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * 10;
    return randomNumber;
}
for(let i=0; i<25; i++){
    randomNumber();
}
```

Now if I change the code call the function inside `console.log()` it does make the 25 calls to the function:

```
function randomNumber(){
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * 10;
    return randomNumber;
}
for(let i=0; i<25; i++){
    console.log(randomNumber());
    
}
```

Comment: Probably some optimization. Since you're not using the value of randomNumber() and it does not have any side effect, the browser optimizes the code and does not call it once it decides it can be safely omitted.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that it makes only one call?

Comment: This function is called every time.

Comment: Your function is called 25 times as expected (add a console.log inside the `randomNumber` function and you'll see). You're simply seeing one value printed to the console because that's what your entire code evaluates to. It's just like typing `Math.random()` and pressing enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you  explicitly add `console.log()` statements to your code, the console only shows the final value that your code evaluates to when it finishes running.  So, you're only seeing one final value in the console which is expected.  If you add a `console.log()` statement anywhere inside the loop, you will then get output for every iteration of the loop.

So, your function is getting called on all 25 iterations of the loop, you just weren't seeing any output from it because it didn't generate any specific output.

For example:

```
function randomNumber(){
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * 10;
    return randomNumber;
}
for(let i=0; i<25; i++){
    let x = randomNumber();
    console.log(x);            // make some visible output in the loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense! so it is the behavior of the console to only show the final value unless it is forced to show them all with console.log()